# MariaDB create table throws error on foreign key contraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mariadb, create-table

Running the following SQL statements (in this order) results in the following error being thrown, I have no idea what's wrong, searched Google for example queries and all seem the same to me.

They work fine when being executed on a MySQL Workbench server but not when I try it on a MariaDb one.

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' CONSTRAINT `playerid` FOREIGN KEY (playerid) REFERENCES st_player (id) ON DELET' at line 1

SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `st_player` (
    `id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    `playerName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `st_statistic` (
    `criteria` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    `subcriteria` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    `playerid` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    `displayname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `amount` INT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`criteria`, `subcriteria`, `playerid`), 
    INDEX `playerid_idx` (`playerid` ASC) VISIBLE, 
    CONSTRAINT `playerid` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`playerid`) REFERENCES `st_player` (`id`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Hi! What version of MySQL server are you using? I think that `VISIBLE` keyword is only available for 8+ versions.

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running a version of MySQL that does not support invisible indexes feature. `VISIBLE` is the default behavior anyway, so you could just remove it from your `create table` statement.

Furthermore, MySQL automatically creates an index on foreign key columns; this means that you don't actually need to explicitly declare that index. I would hence suggest just removing the index declaration.

This codes runs fine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS st_player(
    id VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    playerName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- UNIQUE KEY id(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS st_statistic(
    criteria VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    subcriteria VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    playerid VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    displayname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    amount INT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (criteria,subcriteria,playerid), 
    -- INDEX playerid_idx(playerid ASC), -- unnecessary (but it it is OK if you uncomment it)
    CONSTRAINT playerid
        FOREIGN KEY (playerid) REFERENCES st_player(id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Also please note that you do not need a `unique` index on the primary key column of the first table. A primary key is unique already. I commented that too.